# is there any documentation about your rendering engine available on web

Tags: smartface.io

I am wondering How you are converting from java script code to Android native components, are you doing this using c++ to java calls and do that on the fly. 
so the engine will be installed before on the device ?

Answer (score 1):

First there are three layers. JavaScript, Core and Native (iOS or Android).
JavaScript Engine is based on WebKit's engine named JavaScript Core (JSC), it is directly bound to Core which is written in C++. Native Android part is developed with Java, iOS part is with Objective-C. Between Core & Native layer there is a Bridge Architecture. This bridge establishes communication between Native object and the corresponding object within the Core.
When you do something within JavaScript side, first it updates the Core then Core updates the UI.